# How to mention a instance of AWS DynamoDB in the resource ID while creating application auto scaling target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-auto-scaling

I am setting up the creation of AWS resources in the AWS Cloud Formation template.
I set up my dynamoDb table resource such that with every new stack, it creates a unique instance of the DynamoDb Table, and it's not a fixed name.

I used the following code in the cloud formation template:

```py
 DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    # Retain the table when deleting from CF Stack!
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      #TableName: !Sub "abc-${ClientVar}-DB-${EnvVar}" 
      #TableName: !Ref DbTableName
      TableName: TrackOreDB # This is just for the autoscaling group. I need to find a way to validate it in the autoscaling resource by making the name generic for multiple stacks.
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: Product_ID
          AttributeType: S
        
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: Product_ID
          KeyType: HASH
```

I am trying to set up an application auto-scaling target for this dynamo DB resource with this code. But i am not sure how to point it to the table created above.

```py
  UserTableWriteCapacityScalableTarget: 
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties: 
      MaxCapacity: 100
      MinCapacity: 5   
      ResourceId: !Sub table/'abc-%s-DB-%s' % (client, env)
      RoleARN: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/dynamodb.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
```

At deployment, the auto-scaling resource is getting created before dynamo DB and thus cloud formation deployment is failing.

Please help.

Comment: You control the order of creation with [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference the name of the DynamoDB table resource using `!Ref` or `!Sub` it will output the name of the table.

Cloudformation can detect if a resource is part of another resource definition when `!Ref` and `!Sub` are used and reference the names of other resources.  It will properly order the creation of the resources without requiring `DependsOn` to be explicitly defined.

Assuming this is a YAML Cloudformation template, the two resources in the template would look something like:

```yaml
Resources:
  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: !Sub "abc-${ClientVar}-DB-${EnvVar}" 
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: Product_ID
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: Product_ID
          KeyType: HASH

  UserTableWriteCapacityScalableTarget: 
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties: 
      MaxCapacity: 100
      MinCapacity: 5   
      ResourceId: !Sub "table/${DynamoDBTable}"
      RoleARN: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/dynamodb.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
```